# Solr update semantics with optimistic locking

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4

I face a strange scenario with Solr 4.6.1.

I'm trying to update a document several times. The pseudocode for this:

```
id1 = obtain-the-ID-of-the-document()
lock() 
// only one thread is updating document1
  doc1 = read-document-from-Solr-with-realtime-GET(id1)
  modify-document(doc1)
  update-document-in-Solr(doc1)
unlock()

[...]

id1 = obtain-the-ID-of-the-document()
lock() 
// only one thread is updating document1
  doc1 = read-document-from-Solr-with-realtime-GET(id1)
  modify-document(doc1)
  update-document-in-Solr(doc1)
unlock()
```

Now, I'm using also the optimistic locking mechanism of Solr, mostly to make sure my update logic is fine. And sometimes I stil get "Conflict" from Solr, with status code 409.

It looks like the update operation is returning before the transaction log is being written, because the RealTimeGetHandler does not find the updated version (I know this because the returned document has the same version number). Thus, is possible that the second modification is actually performed on the same document, because both realtime-get queries return the same document; reason for the conflict.

I solved this by adding a small delay in the update method (50-100ms) and re-query Solr until the version numbers are different; at this time I assume that the transaction log is correctly updated and thus I can safely unlock and return to process the next document.

It's really strange to add any delay, is a better way to solve this problem? Or maybe there is some configuration to tell Solr to return from an update only after writing the tlog?

Comment: When the update handler responds, the update is written to the update log. Do you explicitly commit the update to the index?

Comment: Yes. There is a separate job/thread which does that (a hard commit) at every 30 seconds. I'm using the [ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_6_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer.html).